# Cannot use index variable in thymeleaf template after 100th use on an array

Tags: thymeleaf

When I try to use the same variable as an array's index 101th times (even over multiple renderings of my view), I have an exception on evaluating the expression. I have to restart my server to evaluate the expression again (until the 101th evaluation).

```
<th:block th:with="array=${new String[]{'item1'}}, index=0">
    <th:block th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence( 1, 101, 1)}">
        [[${i}]]:[[${array[index]}]]
    </th:block>
</th:block>
```

Result is :

> 1:item1 2:item1 [...] 100:item1 101:

Exception is :

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "array[index]" (template: "test.html" - line 10, col 13)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to instantiate CompiledExpression
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelCompiler.compile(SpelCompiler.java:111)

Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: spel/Ex3, method: getValue signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/expression/EvaluationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;) Expecting to find integer on stack
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
```

Environment is :

- thymeleaf version:'3.0.11.RELEASE'
- thymeleaf-spring5 version:'3.0.11.RELEASE'
- Tomcat 9.0.36
- JDK 1.8.0_74

What's going on ?

Answer (score 0):

The error snippet here mentions that Spring is attempting to compile the expression:

```
SpelCompiler.compile()
```

And, as you note, the problem is very specifically when the code attempts more than 100 array index accesses - even if the index variable never changes:

```
array[index]
```

It's interesting to note that I did not get this error when I hard-coded the index value - for example:

```
array[0]
```

I know of 2 ways around the problem:

**Option 1**

Configure SpEL to not use expression compilation. How you do this depends on your specific config set-up, but the setting is:

```
spring.expression.compiler.mode=off
```

I tried using mode `immediate` and also mode `mixed` - but neither worked. Only mode `off`.

**Option 2**

Avoid using an array with an index variable - for example there is no problem iterating over a list (or an array) like this, where the list contains more than 100 objects:

```
<th:block th:each="i,iterStat : ${myList}">
    [[${iterStat.index}]]:[[${i}]]
</th:block>
```

Whether this option works for you probably depends on the wider context of what your code is doing. So this may not be an option.

Either way, I was surprised that the `mixed` compilation mode did not work. The documentation does note, however, that [there are limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-compiler-limitations) to what the compiler can handle.

*Just as an observation*: I am assuming that you want to use the `[[...]]` syntax in your template, as opposed to something more like this:

```
<th:block th:each="i,iterStat : ${myList}">
    <span th:text="${iterStat.index} + ':' + ${i}"></span>
</th:block>
```

(Doing things this way does not avoid the compilation problem, though.)